# Time off in German

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

I have an appointment during my work hours . I would  like to ask time off for this time plus 2 hours.

Ich habe einen Termin um 15 Uhr. Darf ich von 14 Uhr bis 16 Uhr freinehmen?

Did I translate it correctly?

Comment: The English sentence doesn't mention any times. And my understanding is to ask time off for the start of the appointment and then 2 hours, not one hour around the start of the appointment. If the question is (only) about "taking time off" -> freinehmen. Yes, that's correct.

Comment: ...but there's a little typo: It's not "14 *ihr*" but "14 *Uhr*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

> "Ich habe einen Termin ... Darf ich ... freinehmen?"

is a good way to ask for time off. I would personally use "frei nehmen", but Duden says both variants ("freinehmen", "frei nehmen") are correct.

Comment: Perhaps one should say "Darf ich **mir** von 14 Uhr bis 16 Uhr freinehmen?"